# Is C# System.IO.BinaryFormatter Serialization compatible among the machines implementing C# specification?

Tags: c#, serialization, compatibility

I'm trying to write simple communication program that uses serialization.

I'm curious that whether my binary serialized object will be deserialized properly in other machines implementing C# specification. (if I handle endianness properly)

Specifically, Is System.IO.BinaryFormatter serialization is compatible?

If that is true, It seems to me that if communication noise is negligible,
I may circumvent the overhead of dealing with those string serializations. (like XML or JSON).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not use protocol buffers? https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf

Comment: Are you definitely talking about `BinaryWriter` and not `BinaryFormatter`?

Comment: @MitchWheat Although I am still curious of System.IO.BinaryFormatter compatibility, it seems to be a good alternative and I will take that into consideration. Thank you.

Comment: @John My bad, I will update it at once.